# Problems when drawing multiple objects in sfml

Tags: c++, sprite, sfml

I was wondering what is wrong with my code when I try to draw an object of a class. For my drawable class Box, I have a rectangle shape and a sprite. When I declare an instance of the class to draw in main.cpp, only the Box test(1,1) is drawn properly as I wanted. However, all of the other instances such as Box test1(2,2); Box test2(3,3) were only able to draw the rectangle shape and not the sprite. Is there any way to fix it so that any other instances of object Box is drawn properly like in the case of Box test(1,1)? And the image is loaded properly as the instance test(1,1) demonstrated. Here's my code:

Box.h

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_BOX_H
#define LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_BOX_H


#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Box:public sf::Drawable, sf::Transformable {
protected:
    int col;
    int row;
    sf::Color color;
    sf::RectangleShape boxBackGround;
    sf::Sprite queen;
    sf::Texture texture;
public:
  
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget &window, sf::RenderStates state) const;
    int getRow();
    int getCol();
    void setRow(int row);
    void setCol(int col);
    Box(int row, int col);
    void setBox(int x, int y);
    Box();
    void setTexture();
    void setQueen();
};
```

Box.cpp

```
#include "Box.h"
int Box::getCol() {
    return col;
}
int Box::getRow() {
    return row;
}
void Box::setCol(int col) {
    this->col = col;
}
void Box::setRow(int row) {
    this->row = row;
}
Box::Box(){
    row = 0;
    col = 0;
    this->setBox(this->row,this->col);
    this->setTexture();
    this->setQueen();
}
Box::Box(int row, int col) {
    this->row = row;
    this->col = col;
    this->setBox(this->row,this->col);
    this->setTexture();
    this->setQueen();

}
void Box::setBox(int x, int y) {
    boxBackGround.setSize({200.f,200.f});
    boxBackGround.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    boxBackGround.setPosition(x*210,y*210);
}

void Box::draw(sf::RenderTarget &window, sf::RenderStates state) const {
    window.draw(boxBackGround);
    window.draw(queen);
}
void Box::setTexture() {

    texture.loadFromFile("queen.png");
}
void Box::setQueen() {
    this->queen.setTexture(this->texture);
    this->queen.setScale(0.08f,0.08f);
    this->queen.setPosition(this->boxBackGround.getGlobalBounds().height+50,this->boxBackGround.getGlobalBounds().width+30);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Box.h"
int main() {

    Box test(1,1);
    Box test1(2,2);
    Box test2(3,3);
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1980, 1080, 32), "Test");
    while(window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        window.draw(test2);
        window.draw(test);
        window.draw(test1);
        window.display();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `void Box::setQueen`

In the line:
`this->queen.setPosition(this->boxBackGround.getGlobalBounds().height+50,this->boxBackGround.getGlobalBounds().width+30);`

You should be adding values to the `.top` and `.left` members of the `sf::Rect` returned by the `getGlobalBounds()`. `.width` and `.height` will always be the same for each of boxes' `boxBackGround`, so in your code Queens are all rendered in the same place.

Comment: Thank you, I always got mixed up between those. I fix it now!